# Shader assigned to scene does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, glsl

I've been trying to create a custom shader in my iOS application to add post-processing effect. So, I assign my shader to the scene and see how it is affected in a strange way. It looks like my scene has displacement... Could you be so kind to point where I am wrong. I believe there is a simple explanation I didn't get :)
Thank you in advance.

My test code:

```
var shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "Effect.fsh")

self.shouldEnableEffects = true
self.shader = shader

var node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: size)
node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

self.addChild(node)
```

My simple shader which does nothing:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too when trying to create a blur effect using shaders and an `SKEffectNode` (`SKScene` is actually a subclass of `SKEffectNode` so I believe we have the same problem) I'm pretty sure the offset is a bug with shaders and `SKEffectNode`.

My advice would be to see if there's another way to can achieve the effect you're going for? Perhaps you can apply use the `shader` property on `SKSpriteNode`? That would only apply the shader to that specific node though.

In my situation I was able to adjust the `xScale` and `yScale` of the `SKEffectNode` which made things a marginally better, however it's so much hassle trying to get it in the correct place I'd see if there's another solution before resorting to that.

Good luck!

Comment: I've been struggling with the displacement too. For me changing the coordinates in shader worked:     `vec2 coord = v_tex_coord*0.98;` ... I know it's hack, but was the easiest I've got to work :)